# "Access denied by server" when mounting NFS share

Tags: linux, mount, nfs, freenas

I'm trying to mount an NFS export on an Arch Linux host. It is failing with an "access denied by server" error.

```
[root@client mnt]# showmount -e 192.168.0.45
Export list for 192.168.0.45:
/mnt/Media/stor        (everyone)
[root@client mnt]# mount -t nfs 192.168.0.45:/mnt/Media/stor nas 
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.0.45:/mnt/Media/stor
```

I tried using NFSv3 and v4 and got the same result.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that adding the client name to the `/etc/hosts.allow` file on the server fixes that error message.

```
$ cat /etc/hosts.allow
# /etc/hosts.allow: list of hosts that are allowed to access the system.
#                   See the manual pages hosts_access(5) and hosts_options(5).
#
# Example:    ALL: LOCAL @some_netgroup
#             ALL: .foobar.edu EXCEPT terminalserver.foobar.edu
#
# If you're going to protect the portmapper use the name "rpcbind" for the
# daemon name. See rpcbind(8) and rpc.mountd(8) for further information.
#
ALL: LOCAL client
```

Issue a `sudo exportfs -a` command to ensure that the hosts.allow file is processed.

Comment: Do you think the fact that I'm contacting this server over VPN could be causing this?

Comment: If you think that could be salient information, then why isn't that detail in your original post? I don't know for sure, but the error message you report does not seem to indicate that it would.  The client can apparently contact the server, or else you would get a unreachable-type error.  Instead you're getting a server-is-refusing-access error, i.e. the server is responding, but in a negative way.  BTW you have made no comment as to the result of trying this solution.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work. Same error.

Comment: What exactly did you do?  What's the contents of `/etc/hosts.allow`?  Did you try the IP address as well as the hostname?

Comment: The network-local IP for the client does not have a hostname associated with it. I used the IP address. The contents are "ALL: LOCAL 192.168.0.21 \n ALL: ALL allow"

Comment: Your second line does not look like valid syntax.  Again, be sure to use the `exportfs -a` command.  You could try fixing up `/etc/exports` on the server to explicitly declare the client instead of *"(everyone)"*, e.g. `/mnt/Media/stor         192.168.0.21(rw,no_subtree_check)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58822/discussion-between-nathan-and-sawdust).